WinUI 3 ProgressRing when loading page from MainWindow
I have a Winui 3 App with a MainWindow and 2 Pages at the moment. I'm using a NavigationView to navigate to the Pages.
I want to have a ProgressRing shown while navigating to the page.
I tried to set it as following:
MainWindow.xaml.cs:
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var root = this.Content as FrameworkElement;
        if (root != null)
            root.Loaded += async (s, e) => await DisplayDialog();

        prgr.IsActive = false;
    }

    private void NavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = sender.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>().First(x => (string)x.Content == (string)args.InvokedItem);
        Navigate(item);
        prgr.IsActive = false;
    }

    private void Navigate(NavigationViewItem item)
    {
        prgr.IsActive = true;
        try
        {
            switch (item.Tag)
            {
                case "tabellenView":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(TabellenView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
                case "sqlScriptsView":
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SqlScriptsView), null, new DrillInNavigationTransitionInfo());
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SentrySdk.CaptureException(e);
        }
    }

    private async Task DisplayDialog()
    {
        await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void contentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!DatabaseConnectionService.IsConnected)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window
    x:Class="DatenbankAdminGui.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:DatenbankAdminGui"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:control="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:viewmodel="using:DatenbankAdminGui.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Datenbank Admin"
    >
    
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="gd">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>

        <NavigationView   x:Name="NavView" ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked" IsSettingsVisible="False">

            <NavigationView.PaneHeader>
                
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                        <Ellipse Height="75" Width="75" Margin="5">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>

                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}">
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="User:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Username}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"/>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Database:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Configstring.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10"/>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="DB-Version: " HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DatabaseVersion}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10"/>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>

                    <ProgressRing Name="prgr"/>

                </StackPanel>
                
            </NavigationView.PaneHeader>
            
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>

                <NavigationViewItem Content="Tabellen" Tag="tabellenView" Icon="PhoneBook"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="SQL Scripts" Tag="sqlScriptsView" Icon="Folder"/>

            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>
            </Frame>
        </NavigationView>

        <control:ContentDialog x:Name="contentDialog" Width="800" Height="800" Title="Login Window" CloseButtonText="Abbrechen" PrimaryButtonText="Login" CloseButtonCommand="{Binding CloseDialogCommand}" Closing="contentDialog_Closing" PrimaryButtonCommand="{Binding LoginCommand}">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    <TextBlock Text="Login-Name" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Passwort" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>

                    <TextBlock Text="Data Source Name" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
                    <PasswordBox Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
                    <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigStrings, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Configstring, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Notification, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                </Grid>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            </Grid>
        </control:ContentDialog>

    </Grid>
</Window>


But when I click on the Tab in the NavigationView, I'll be navigated but the ProgressRing isn't shown while Navigating.
Can you help me?

There are many problems with your code, most of them stemming from misuse of IoC (you're using pure imperative calls like it's the 90s and you're coding a Win32 GUI in C) and, unfortunately, one stemming from a misunderstanding of application message processing -- the issue you're having.
If you read through the spaghetti mess, the progress ring is shown when the navigation is triggered by the tab view, then the frame loads the new view, then it hides the progress ring. At no point does the message loop actually run to render the progress ring -- you're holding the GUI thread hostage with synchronously loading the page.
Now, if loading takes so long that you need a progress ring, you should separate whatever is taking a long time into a task and await it before navigating the frame, which would show the progress ring, because the message loop would run while awaiting the task and the window could render itself.

The navigation, including the status switch on ProcessRing.IsActive will be run on the main thread. So you are activating the ProcessRing then deactivating it immediately.
If you have any heavy (time-taking) work when you navigate to the page, you should put it on a asynchronous method and call it while navigating.
For example:
PageA
<TextBlock
    x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
    Text="Page A" />

public async Task Initialize()
{
    // The UI thread will be freed here.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    // The UI thread will return after 3 sec.

    TitleTextBlock.Text = "Page A initialized!";
}

PageB
<TextBlock
    x:Name="TitleTextBlock"
    Text="Page B" />

public async Task Initialize()
{
    // The UI thread will be freed here.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    // The UI thread will return after 3 sec.

    TitleTextBlock.Text = "Page B initialized!";
}

and MainWindow.xaml should look something like this:
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            x:Name="PageAButton"
            Click="PageAButton_Click"
            Content="Page A" />
        <Button
            x:Name="PageBButton"
            Click="PageBButton_Click"
            Content="Page B" />
        <ProgressRing
            x:Name="NavigatingProgressRing"
            IsActive="False" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Frame
        x:Name="ContentFrame"
        Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>

private async void PageAButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigatingProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageA));

    if (ContentFrame.Content is PageA pageA)
    {
        await pageA.Initialize();
    }

    NavigatingProgressRing.IsActive = false;
}

private async void PageBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigatingProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageB));

    if (ContentFrame.Content is PageB pageB)
    {
        await pageB.Initialize();
    }

    NavigatingProgressRing.IsActive = false;
}

